# Disable keyboard on EditText

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm doing a calculator.
So I made my own `Buttons` with numbers and functions.
The expression that has to be calculated, is in an `EditText`, because I want users can add numbers or functions also in the middle of the expression, so with the `EditText` I have the `cursor`. But I want to disable the `Keyboard` when users click on the `EditText`.
I found this example that it's ok for `Android 2.3`, but with `ICS` disable the `Keyboard` and also the cursor.

```
public class NoImeEditText extends EditText {

   public NoImeEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
      super(context, attrs);     
   }   

   @Override      
   public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {   
       return false;     
   }         
}
```

And then I use this `NoImeEditText` in my `XML` file

```
<com.my.package.NoImeEditText
      android:id="@+id/etMy"
 ....  
/>
```

How I can make compatible this EditText with ICS???
Thanks.

Comment: How did you make each button to put the text in the correct place in the EditText (on the text cursor/caret) ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[Here](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/180530f680374493?pli=1) is a website that will give you what you need

As a summary, it provides links to `InputMethodManager` and `View` from Android Developers. It will reference to the `getWindowToken` inside of `View` and `hideSoftInputFromWindow()` for `InputMethodManager`

A better answer is given in the link, hope this helps.

here is an example to consume the onTouch event:

```
editText_input_field.setOnTouchListener(otl);

private OnTouchListener otl = new OnTouchListener() {
  public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true; // the listener has consumed the event
  }
};
```

Here is another example from the same website. This claims to work but seems like a bad idea since your EditBox is NULL it will be no longer an editor:

```
MyEditor.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int inType = MyEditor.getInputType(); // backup the input type
    MyEditor.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // disable soft input
    MyEditor.onTouchEvent(event); // call native handler
    MyEditor.setInputType(inType); // restore input type
    return true; // consume touch even
  }
});
```

Hope this points you in the right direction

Comment: The second example is the solution :D thanks! Works also with ICS... the other examples works only on old versions of Android like 2.3....

Comment: Not working well for a multiline EditText in 2.1. The view distorting after such a trick. Scrolling and cursor aren't working either.

Comment: Seems a bit of a hack for something so simple.

Comment: I don't know why but it can't work with cursor after adding this code :-(

Comment: etSearchEnglish.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // disable showing keyboard , works for me !

Answer (score 62):

Below code is both for API >= 11 and API < 11. Cursor is still available.

```
/**
 * Disable soft keyboard from appearing, use in conjunction with android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustNothing"
 * @param editText
 */
public static void disableSoftInputFromAppearing(EditText editText) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
    } else {
        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        editText.setFocusable(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: any ideas how to enable keyboard back after using this disable method ?

Comment: yeah. It is good question @kort.es .. Please answer Aleksey, how?

Comment: Since API >= 11 is very common, the same could be achieved by using xml parameters: 
`android:inputType="text"
android:textIsSelectable="true"`

Comment: Instead of simply `editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);` I use `editText.setRawInputType(editText.getInputType());` - this ensures that any inputType settings in the XML are maintained.

Comment: `setRawInputType(...)` is better than `setInputType(0)` because it didn't disable the cursor.

Comment: This code doesn't work on Samsung Galaxy S5 (klte, Android 6.0). Today I've received a review from a user. Is there any solution?

Comment: great job sir . I found this solution after many search and it really works better than `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)`. still cursor visible . thanks.

Comment: The problem with this is that it causes multi-line things to be single line.

Answer (score 37):

You can also use [setShowSoftInputOnFocus(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setShowSoftInputOnFocus(boolean)) directly on API 21+ or through reflection on API 14+:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
} else {
    try {
        final Method method = EditText.class.getMethod(
                "setShowSoftInputOnFocus"
                , new Class[]{boolean.class});
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(editText, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea is good, however it doesn't work with API 14-15, but works with 16+. For API 15 it's possible to use method named "setSoftInputShownOnFocus".

Comment: I can't upvote this enough!!!! Thank you Android for a simple solution for a long time problem!

Answer (score 33):

Add below properties to the Edittext controller in the layout file

```
<Edittext
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
   android:cursorVisible="false"
   android:focusable="false"  />
```

I have been using this solution for while and it works fine for me.

Comment: It's the quickest way :P

Answer (score 29):

```
editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

Comment: This answer is better than others for my needs, because i need my EditText to be active to other touch events, like the "setError" message. Disabling focus will disable all touch events too.

Comment: Finally the only answer that worked. And was so simple...... <3

Answer (score 22):

try: `android:editable="false"` or `android:inputType="none"`

Answer (score 16):

### Disable the keyboard (API 11 to current)

This is the best answer I have found so far to disable the keyboard (and I have seen a lot of them).

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { // API 21
    editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
} else { // API 11-20
    editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
}
```

There is no need to use reflection or set the `InputType` to null.

### Re-enable the keyboard

Here is how you re-enable the keyboard if needed.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { // API 21
    editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(true);
} else { // API 11-20
    editText.setTextIsSelectable(false);
    editText.setFocusable(true);
    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    editText.setClickable(true);
    editText.setLongClickable(true);
    editText.setMovementMethod(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.getInstance());
    editText.setText(editText.getText(), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

See this Q&A for why the complicated pre API 21 version is needed to undo `setTextIsSelectable(true)`:

- [How to enable keyboard on touch after disabling it with setTextIsSelectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228531/how-to-enable-keyboard-on-touch-after-disabling-it-with-settextisselectable)

## This answer needs to be more thoroughly tested.

I have tested the `setShowSoftInputOnFocus` on higher API devices, but after @androiddeveloper's comment below, I see that this needs to be more thoroughly tested.

Here is some cut-and-paste code to help test this answer. If you can confirm that it does or doesn't work for API 11 to 20, please leave a comment. I don't have any API 11-20 devices and my emulator is having problems.

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:text="enable keyboard"
        android:onClick="enableButtonClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:text="disable keyboard"
        android:onClick="disableButtonClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    }

    // when keyboard is hidden it should appear when editText is clicked
    public void enableButtonClick(View view) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { // API 21
            editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(true);
        } else { // API 11-20
            editText.setTextIsSelectable(false);
            editText.setFocusable(true);
            editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            editText.setClickable(true);
            editText.setLongClickable(true);
            editText.setMovementMethod(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.getInstance());
            editText.setText(editText.getText(), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        }
    }

    // when keyboard is hidden it shouldn't respond when editText is clicked
    public void disableButtonClick(View view) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { // API 21
            editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
        } else { // API 11-20
            editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For the older versions, this seems like a weird choice to use "setTextIsSelectable" . Its name doesn't imply it should work this way. Did you test it on a lot of devices?

Comment: @androiddeveloper, I didn't test it on a lot of devices. I'm trying to test it on the lower API's now but I'm having trouble with my emulator. If you or anyone else can confirm that it does or doesn't work, please leave another comment.

Comment: Well it worked fine on the few devices I've tested, but so did the reflection methods I've found (written about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45274277/878126 ) . Reflection in general is considered a dangerous thing to use, but the reflected functions have better name than "setTextIsSelectable".

Comment: @androiddeveloper, specifically which pre API 21 device did you use to test `setTextIsSelectable`?

Comment: I think one of them is called "Samsung Galaxy Young".

Comment: @androiddeveloper, Oh, sorry, I mean which API level?

Comment: I think it had Jelly Bean.

Answer (score 9):

Gathering solutions from multiple places here on StackOverflow, I think the next one sums it up:

If you don't need the keyboard to be shown anywhere on your activity, you can simply use the next flags which are used for dialogs (got from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10439581/878126)) :

```
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
```

If you don't want it only for a specific EditText, you can use this (got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26648367/878126)) :

```
public static boolean disableKeyboardForEditText(@NonNull EditText editText) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
        return true;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1)
        try {
            final Method method = EditText.class.getMethod("setShowSoftInputOnFocus", new Class[]{boolean.class});
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(editText, false);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
        try {
            Method method = TextView.class.getMethod("setSoftInputShownOnFocus", boolean.class);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(editText, false);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    return false;
}
```

Or this (taken from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45229457/878126)) :

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
           editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
       else
           editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Comment: I'm going to try testing the flags solution more. Which API levels have you already tested it on?

Comment: "If you don't want it only for...": I think you meant to say, "If you only want it for..."

Comment: It's "don't want", because it blocks the keyboard from showing. Don't want to show keyboard => the keyboard won't be shown.

Comment: About API levels, I've tried it on Android 6.0.x, 4.2.x, and 5.x (don't remember the exact ones).

Comment: OK, I took "it" to mean the disabling, but now I understand that you meant it as the keyboard.

Comment: Finally! getWindow().setFlags did the trick. I have been searching everywhere on the internet to find a way to remove (keep always hidden) the native keyboard since I use a custom one inside the app and nothing worked (consider also having a focused edit text, move app to background and bring it back, that would always bring the native keyboard back). Setting this flags in the main activity on create was the solution. Thank you!!

Comment: @RedDeath Please note: 1. I think there are newer APIs now related to keyboards. Not sure. 2. When hiding the keyboard, on new Android versions, the autofill might not work at all (because it's shown as part of the keyboard)

Comment: @androiddeveloper trust me there are not newer APIs that solve having custom keyboards for an app (I had to fork google's code and tweak the implementation myself). And regarding the autofill I don't really care because is not a feature I want to support in the app. So honestly this is a perfect solution to my issue

Answer (score 6):

To add to Alex Kucherenko solution: the issue with the cursor getting disappearing after calling `setInputType(0)` is due to a framework bug on ICS (and JB).

The bug is documented here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27609.

To workaround this, call `setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)` right after the `setInputType` call.

To stop the keyboard from appearing, just override `OnTouchListener` of the EditText and return true (swallowing the touch event):

```
ed.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                return true;
            }
        });
```

The reasons for the cursor appearing on GB devices and not on ICS+ had me tearing my hair out for a couple of hours, so I hope this saves someone's time.

Comment: setInputType+setRawInputType don't work, as it will still show the keyboard. when focusing using touch events. Adding setOnTouchListener the way you did will solve this, but then it doesn't allow to change the location of the caret or selection of text.

Answer (score 6):

I found this solution which works for me. It also places the cursor, when clicked on EditText at the correct position.

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_mine);
// set OnTouchListener to consume the touch event
editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.onTouchEvent(event);   // handle the event first
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if (imm != null) {
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);  // hide the soft keyboard 
            }                
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This implementation slows down the cursor reaction after touch very much (about 1 second delay) on my Nexus 10

Answer (score 5):

```
// only if you completely want to disable keyboard for 
// that particular edit text
your_edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_1);
your_edit_text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Comment: This causes the cursor to disappear on ICS+ devices due to framework bug. See my answer below for a possible solution.

Answer (score 4):

Just set:

```
 NoImeEditText.setInputType(0);
```

or in the constructor:

```
   public NoImeEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
          super(context, attrs);   
          setInputType(0);
       }
```

Comment: On Android 2.1-2.3 this is OK, but with ICS it disable also the cursor =( I don't know why... =(

Comment: I have checked one of my Apps, you are right. Thanks for comment

Answer (score 3):

Just put this line inside the activity tag in manifest
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.
First add this `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in your android manifest file, under your activity.  like below:

```
<activity ... android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
```

Then on onCreate method of youractivity, add the foloowing code:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
edit_text.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.onTouchEvent(event);
        InputMethodManager inputMethod = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (inputMethod!= null) {
            inputMethod.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }                
        return true;
    }
});
```

Then if you want the pointer to be visible add this on your xml  `android:textIsSelectable="true"`.

This will make the pointer visible.
In this way the keyboard will not popup when your activity starts and also will be hidden when you click on the edittext.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, these lines work for me...

```
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:cursorVisible="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
```

before adding these lines, When I clicked on editText default keyboard showed/invoked.
[image]

After adding these lines keyboard was not displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to disable keyboard on EditText is

```
binding.InputTextView.showSoftInputOnFocus = false
```

Answer (score 0):

For Edit Text use the attribute android:focusable="false"

Answer (score -2):

I don´t know if this answer is the better, but i found a possible faster solution. On XML, just put on EditText this attributes:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

And then do what you need with onClickListener.