# How to disable the default keyboard in EditText, allowing the other actions

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText, since I use a custom keyboard in my App, I have disabled the standard android keyboard.
Unfortunately now seems that I cannot use the copy paste, selection etc when I click on the EditText in Jelly Bean, in Gingerbread my edit text has the desired behavior.

I need simply to disable the android keyboard to use my custom keyboard but the others copy-paste actions, selection etc, must be active

How could I fix this?

My EditText is this:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:background="@color/light_sky"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:editable="true"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoEnterAction|flagNoExtractUi"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="32dip" />
```

Comment: You see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: @PANDA
Yes but doesn't work. The keyboard is showed when I click the EditText widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You proably have set a null input in your EditText.

If other situations you can prevent the keyboard showing simply using in the manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

In this way the Android keyboard will not auto-open but is shown only if you click directly the EditText

Answer (score 2):

Building on this topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636686/2558337 i suppose that you should `@Override` `onClickListener`

```
inputField.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could even try this that works

declare a InputMethodManager variable   `private InputMethodManager imm;`

And in your `onActivityCreated()` method add these lines

```
// to hide the keypad
imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(inputSearch.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

And to unhide use the following code

```
editText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           imm.showSoftInput(inputSearch, 0);
      }
});
```