# Detect when the mobile keyboard is shown or dismissed in HTML5 web

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

In a mobile device, when you focus on a textfield, the keyboard is shown.

I want detect when the keyboard is shown or dismissed and these actions are different in each mobile technology. Android, for example, doesn't fire a blur event when the keyboard is closed.

Is there a cross-browser means of subscribing to these events?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable keyboard on EditText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636635/disable-keyboard-on-edittext)

Comment: I want detect when the keyboard shows or dismiss, not disable keyboard  and it isn't a native app, is a web app. Sorry if my explanation is bad :)

Comment: I've written a small snippet for dealing with that: https://github.com/zvona/Servant.js . Hope it helps. Although it's iOS only :(

Comment: Thanks but I need a cross platform solution :)

Comment: use `focusin` and `focusout` events.

Comment: Thanks @Omar but when push back button in mobile device don't fires focusout event