# How to Disable Keyboard on multiple EditTexts

Tags: android

I have an app which converts `meters` to `centimeters` , simple, right?

So i have two parts on it. One being the keypad and the other one are the two `edittext` boxes.

i was using my own keypad, so there was no sense for android keyboard to show up.

I looked upon various answers and they don't seem to work for me.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636635/disable-keyboard-on-edittext)  question asks the same thing and i implemented the selected answer but the edittexts are behaving weirdly.

[image]

First one seem to work as i wanted it to work but somehow the other text won't come on focus.

I try to click on it and nothing happens.The focus just won't go from the first one.

**What i tried**

```
    findViewById(R.id.lengthConverterSecond).setOnTouchListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.lengthConverterFirst).setOnTouchListener(this);
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return true;
    }
```

What's up with this weird behavior?

What would be the solution to my above problem?

**update**

Tried this tooo.

Just in case

```
findViewById(R.id.lengthConverterSecond).setOnFocusChangeListener(this);         findViewById(R.id.lengthConverterFirst).setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if(b){
                InputMethodManager im=(InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                assert im != null;
                im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);
            }
        }
```

This doesn't work at all, like it won't hide the keyboard but that weird behavior i witnessed above,doesn't happen now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for minSdk=8 and maxSdk=23

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

for API 21 or >21

If you are having two edit text ( suppose editText1 and editText2)  and you want to use your own custom keyboard then use this solution.

```
 EditText editText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 EditText editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);

 editText1.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);  // add this if you dont want default keyboard when you tap on editText1.

 editText2.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);// add this if you dont want default keyboard when you tap on editText2.
```

here

Comment: added for for minSdk=8 and maxSdk=23 too check updated code

Comment: `public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.lengthConverterFirst:{
                view.requestFocus();
            }
            case R.id.lengthConverterSecond:{
                view.requestFocus();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }`

Comment: did this^
Worked for me