# How to completly disable softkeyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm developing an app for 3 different type of devices and I've started with full touch one by adding different kind of focuses on editText's and co.

But the other two devices has one reduced hardware keyboard and another one large hardware keyboard so i would be able to completely disable the usage of the softkeyboard if I'm using one of the two last listed devices.

I've tried all the methods mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) question but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Detect which kind of keyboard is currently installed on the device. 
Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration#keyboard

Step 2: Change the edit text attributes in runtime to handle your situation. 
[Disable keyboard on EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636635/disable-keyboard-on-edittext)