# How to implement edittext where the input is only accepted by a stylus or a finger, just like in the notetaking applications?

Tags: java, android, android-developer-api

I making a survey application whereby the clients fill the questionnaire and when done, the last step involves appending a signature using his finger or stylus before saving the input data to a database?Thus I need help on how to implement this signature edit text so that it accepts input either by finger or stylus

Comment: Typically you just turn off the keyboard, that way the input doesn't trigger it.

I think this answer might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636635/disable-keyboard-on-edittext

Answer (score 0):

thanks, all for the answers. After further research, I found out a tutorial that implements exactly what I wanted. [How to implement a custom layout that accepts finger or stylus input and not keyboard](https://acomputerengineer.wordpress.com/2018/08/25/draw-line-using-finger-on-canvas-in-android/)