# How to make EditText ediable but disable no keyboard?

Tags: android

I made a calculator. Its working fine. I want to have touch focus in edittext but the problem is when i touch it the keyboard popup. How to disable keyboard?

[Screenshot of Calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIuWw.jpg)

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="bottom|end"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:id="@+id/tvExpression_ID"/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable keyboard on EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636635/disable-keyboard-on-edittext)

Comment: `android:clickable="false"` and `android:focusable="false"` will work for you

Comment: keyboard is disabled but the touch focus is lost.

Comment: If possible then can you add screenshot after making changes

Comment: I am new  stackoverflow. I dont know where to send it. I want only make edittext editable to make changes but with no keyboard.

Comment: are you SURE touch focus is lost?  The click event is triggered by touch, but there is also a separate touch event.

Comment: yes sir touch focus is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in Manifest file
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"`  or 
set this for your edittext
    `android:textIsSelectable="true"`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before and this solution works for me

```
 <EditText
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:focusable="false"  />
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

use this three line code to solve your issue

```
etText = findViewById(R.id.etText);
etText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
etText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Comment: check this Link
https://medium.com/@ssaurel/creating-an-in-app-keyboard-for-your-android-apps-a0a6c6e1e289