# Dismiss Keyboard in Android Automatically

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create calculator application in Android Studio using Java, I have EditText for showing result. When I focus this input Keyboard is showing. But I don't want to see keyboard in focus event as in normal calculator. Is there any way to solve this, or can I use other element either than EditText, I have used `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);` in OnCreate method, but it doesn't work

Comment: editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EditText` is desired to.. edit text. do you want to allow user for editing result?

if not just replace `EditText` with `TextView` and then any keyboard won't show up

if you still want this field to be editable then take a look a [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636635/disable-keyboard-on-edittext) QA, you will find there plenty of methods for blocking keyboard pop up automatically