# disable android device keyboard appearing when selecting an edit box

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, pascal

I have a point of sales screen created for users to purchase products, And have created my own keyboard on the screen. However when I deploy to an android device the android keyboard pops up when I select the edt box. How do I stop the Android devices keyboard from appearing as I need to use the keyboard I created.

Comment: Use the `VKAutoShowMode` variable (`FMX.Types` unit). Set it to `TVKAutoShowMode.Never` to prevent the Virtual Keyboard from showing, for anything

Comment: Probably you are looking for this solutions https://stackoverflow.com/a/17200101/10248593 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636686/10248593

Answer (score 0):

FMX.Types.VKAutoShowMode := TVKAutoShowMode.Never;